# php, проблема с авторизацией, сесия

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

никак немогу понять почему после разлогиневания не получается авторизироватся повторно, приходится чистить куки и только тогда авторизация работает снова

вот код проверки логина

```
# Авторизация
session_set_cookie_params(1800,"/");
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
print_r($_COOKIE);

if (!$mPartner->CheckLogin())
{
    $no_header = true;
    $content = '
    <h1>Не можете войти?</h1><br />
    <p>Можете зарегистрироваться в партнёрской программе.</p>
    <p><a href="new.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Перейти к регистрации</a></p>
    <br /><br />
    <p>Или восстановить пароль, если вы его потеряли.</p>
    <p><a href="restore.php" class="btn btn-primary">Восстановление пароля</a></p>';
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../design/partnerCreate.tpl.php';
    die;
}

/**
    * Функция авторизации
    *
    * @return boolean
    */
    public function CheckLogin()
    {
        global $config;
        $login_successful = false;

        $logout = (isset($_SESSION['logout'])) ? $_SESSION['logout'] : false;

        # Проверка логина и пароля
        if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
        {
            $params = array ('email =', 'password =');
            $values = array ('\'' . mysqli_real_escape_string($this->mysqli_db, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) . '\'', '\'' . mysqli_real_escape_string($this->mysqli_db, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) . '\'');
            $search_type = array ('AND');

            $result = $this->mDB->SearchItemsByParamArray('partner', $params, $values, $search_type);

            if ($result == true && $logout != true)
            {
                $_SESSION['id_partner'] = $result[0]['id_partner'];
                $login_successful = true;
            }
        }

        # Если юзер не залогинен
        if (!$login_successful)
        {
            # Форма авторизации
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Enter login and password"');
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

        public function Login($login, $password)
    {
        global $config;

        $login = trim($login);
        $password = trim($password);

        # проверка пароля
        if (md5($password) != $config['partner']['password'] || $login != $config['partner']['login'])
            return false;

        # открытие сессии
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['is_partner'] = true;
        $_SESSION['logout'] = false;
        unset($_SESSION['logout']);

        return true;
    }
}
```

а это код разлогиневания

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logout'] = true;
    $_SESSION['id_partner'] = false;

unset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]);
setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", time() - 100);

header('Location: index.php');
```

причем куки так и не удаляются почему-то

**UP:**
попробовал так:

```
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');
```

после перенапавления на index.php команда: print_r($_SESSION);
выдает следующее:

```
Array
(
    [id_partner] => 5
)
```

Comment: А чем `session_destroy()` не угодил ?

Comment: пробовал... не помогло, обновил вопрос

Comment: `setcookie("cookie_name", "", 0)` куки можно удалить таким образом

Comment: Зачем удалять с кук идентификатор сессии ? Вот так сделай при логауте `session_destroy();header('Location: index.php');exit();` . Всё что было в сессии будет удалено

Answer (score 0):

> Цитата:
>   session_destroy();
>   header('Location: index.php');

Функция [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-destroy.php) уничтожает все данные, связанные с текущей сессией, но не удаляет какие-либо глобальные переменные, связанные с сессией и не удаляет сессионные cookie.

Попробуйте использовать [session_unset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-unset.php)